# Create a subset of an xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am looking to create a subset of an xml file using python for testing.  In the example xml below I would like to extract all records with an item date of "January 2015" and create a new xml file with just these records.  any help would be much appreciated!

```
<config>
  <item date="January 2015">
    <mode>1</mode>
    <current>1</current>
  </item>
  <item date="February 2016">
    <mode>9</mode>
    <current>100</current>
  </item>
  <item date="January 2015">
    <mode>9</mode>
    <current>100</current>
  </item>
</config>
```

Comment: please show what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and [XPath expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(open('data.xml'))

unwanted = tree.xpath("//item[not(@date='January 2015')]")
for node in unwanted:
    node.getparent().remove(node)

with open('filtered.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

- The expression `//item` would match all `<item />` nodes in the document
- `[@date='January 2015']` would then restrict the selection to only the `<item />` nodes that have an attribute `date` that is equal to `January 2015`
- The `not()` around it inverts that condition, in order to get the `<item />` nodes to **drop** from the tree
- These then get filtered from the tree by removing the node *from its parent*

For more details on XPath expression see this [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) for example.

---

Output in `filtered.xml`:

```xml
<config>
  <item date="January 2015">
    <mode>1</mode>
    <current>1</current>
  </item>
  <item date="January 2015">
    <mode>9</mode>
    <current>100</current>
  </item>
</config>
```

Comment: thanks Lukas that worked perfectly!  if I wanted to remove nodes where the mode = 9 from my example xml above what would I need to do?  I have tried altering the python but I keep ending with a blank file.